# Forward to the JSP of which this piece of code caused an error: <c:forEach items="${order.OrderItemList}" var="item">

Tags: jsp, servlets

The Bean and JSP are below:

```html
public class Order {
    private String o_id;
    private User user;
    private Timestamp time;
    private int state;
    private String address;
    private double total;

    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
        return OrderItemList;
    }

    public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
        OrderItemList = orderItemList;
    }
}

<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">   // Outer loop for orders
<c:forEach items="${order.OrderItemList}" var="item">  // Inner loop for items of an order
```

And I'm sure that OrderItemList isn't empty and is truly transferred to the JSP file.

In my limited experience with Servlet, I think `${order.OrderItemList}` is not the correct expression when the element of the Bean is a List. Is that true?

Comment: The JavaBean property is named `orderItemList`, not `OrderItemList`. And you should respect the Java naming conventions and rename the field to `orderItemList, too. The field would then have the same name as the property, which would make it less confusing.

Comment: oh my god.  the problem is really what you said. one hour is for coding with ten hours debugging. it almost makes me crazy.

Comment: @JBNizet and thanks for your help.